# Should I use HTTP response codes to fire jQuery's ajax error callback?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

I've built a file uploader with utilises cmlenz's jquery-iframe-transport. 
In the $.ajax call I'd like to handle errors via the error callback.
This can be done by having the server send a HTTP error code (4xx or 5xx) with my error message.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/upload',
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Handle error here
    }
});
```

An alternative would be to parse the success callback, detect an error and handle it then.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/upload',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        if(data && data.hasOwnProperty('error') {
            // Handle error here
        }
    }
});
```

Basically my question is should I manipulate the HTTP response codes on the server side so I can easily handle errors on the client side? Do all browsers behave the same when it comes to HTTP error codes and ajax? Or is this just a violation of misusing the HTTP?

Comment: It's a bit subjective, but I've started using the HTTP error codes for all my API's. It seems more idiomatic, and portable. By portable I mean that the error codes are constrained by the specification, and therefore easier to document and consume. Whereas something custom will only ever make sense for you API.

Comment: What about browser compatibility? Do all browsers behave the same when they receive a HTTP error code from the server? According to standards in HTTP can you send body content with these error codes?

Comment: I think you are going to get pretty similar results from nearly all modern browsers. And since you are using jQuery, then you won't have any problems using the error callback. As for including data... *yes* you can include a body, and in fact are encouraged to do so by the HTTP Specification. I usually include a JSON response that has error information in a structured fashion.

Comment: Cheers, just the advice i was hoping for

Answer (score 0):

HTTP errors are the *correct* thing to do, but [they won't work with the `<iframe>` transport](http://cmlenz.github.com/jquery-iframe-transport/#section-13).